# issue in using currency manager in web applications c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page where I want to display records from sql database in textboxes. I have 4 buttons First, Next, Previous and Last respectively. The problem is I cannot display records using currency manager in web applications. When I try to use it I get an error that "I am missing an assembly reference or a directive. I have tried the solution of adding the namespace by right clicking the solution explorer and adding reference but it is not added. I am using visual studio 2012 and asp.net 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 1):

[`CurrencyManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a *WinForms* component.  You can't use it in ASP.NET.

> When I try to use it I get an error that "I am missing an assembly reference or a directive.

You can probably get the code to *compile* if you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, but it's going to fail at runtime because WinForms components don't work in ASP.NET.

Comment: So is there a way to overcome the runtime failure. Thanks for the help

Comment: @meghasingh: No.  WinForms components don't work in ASP.NET.  They're two completely different technology stacks.  If you're writing web applications then you need to familiarize yourself with the toolsets for that technology stack.  You can't just copy/paste your WinForms code there.